# ASP.NET app which worked fine on IIS 6 is not working correctly in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis

I have a web app which is working fine in IIS 6 ex:loading page, loading  doc and excel file perfectly. recently I moved the same web app code ti windows server 2008 R2 IIS 7. Now it is not working correctly, it is browsing but it is not loading the Excel and doc files properly.

**Additonal Trouble Shooting Info**

Adding to the above when i checked the event viewer i am getting below information

The description for Event ID 0 from source Quotes cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

```
If the event originated on another computer,
the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Class : GetFile Method : Page_Load An unexpected error has occurred
while locally saving the requested file. Error details -  Object
reference not set to an instance of an object. the message resource is
present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

could you please help on this. how to find the root error and how to trouble shoot further.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the response code for the request? Check the request with FireFox/Chrome console

Comment: Your question lacks details needed to help resolve the issue. *How* are you loading Excel and Word files in your application? Are you running IIS on a 64-bit machine, and which version of Office (if you're using that) do you have?  Any error messages?  What have you tried to resolve the problem, and what results did you get?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but we had an issue where we used to parse data Excel worksheets using Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0

This started to throw errors on an Application hosted within IIS7 but was fine in IIS6.

Our fix was to:

- Right click the Application Pool being used by the Web App
- Advanced Settings
- Set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True

If that fails to help, why not try to use the Classic .NET AppPool with your application, as opposed to the DefaultAppPool (which I am assuming is the case).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 For Set enable 32-Bit, I've been stung by this one